# Can we either print or plot in Shiny in same panel?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to either call

```
 output$IPLMatchPlot <- renderPlot({ 

 f(x)
```

})
     or

```
 output$IPLMatchPrint <- renderPrint({
   f(x)
 })
```

The function f(x) either returns a plot or a data frame.

I am able to do this separately in the server.R but would like to the display to be either a plot or the text of the data frame. Any suggestions of how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be handled by using a renderUI() which checks what kind of output it's getting and renders the appropriate output.

In the UI part you would place a `uiOutput` in the place where you want the plot or print to show up.

```
uiOutput("Plotorprint")
```

and then in the server you would define that `uiOutput` with something like this:

```
  output$Plotorprint <- renderUI({
    if (is.data.frame(f(x))) { # Check if output of f(x) is data.frame
      verbatimTextOutput("ISPLMatchPrint") # If so, create a print
    } else {                      # If not,
      plotOutput("ISPLMatchPlot") # create a plot
    }
  })
```

And you would keep the definitions you posted in your question in your server as well.

This should then check what output f(x) is getting, and render the appropriate output.

Comment: @Marjin - The solution looks right but I am running into issues. I added in ui. R -  uiOutput('Plotorprint') & in server.R the following lines for just printing the text ==>  output$Plotorprint <-  renderUI({  
        a <-f(x)
        verbatimTextOutput(a)   }). This prints an empty box

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow

Comment: output$IPLMatchPlot <- renderPlot({ 
         printOrPlot(input, output,teams, otherTeam)    
    })
    output$IPLMatchPrint <- renderPlot({         
        df <-printOrPlot(input, output,teams, otherTeam)
       df
    })                                                                                output$Plotorprint <-  renderUI({ 
        if(is.data.frame(scorecard <- printOrPlot(input, output,teams, otherTeam))){
            verbatimTextOutput("IPLMatchPrint")
        }
        else{
            plotOutput("IPLMatchPlot")
        }   The plot shows up but not dataframe.

Comment: I realized after adding the above comment that I had 'renderPlot' instead of 'renderPrint'. I changed it and it worked.. like magic! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The final code based on @Marjin's response is

server.R

```
output$IPLMatchPlot <- renderPlot({        
     f(x,y,z)


})
output$IPLMatchPrint <- renderPrint({        
    df <- f(x,y,z)
    df
})

output$plotOrPrint <-  renderUI({  
    if(is.data.frame(scorecard <- printOrPlot(input, output,teams, otherTeam))){
        verbatimTextOutput("IPLMatchPrint")
    }
    else{
        plotOutput("IPLMatchPlot")
    }
})
```

ui.R

```
 uiOutput("plotOrPrint"),
```