# How to renderPrint?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a console and enter code to display in the panel.
Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382350/9220442), I created this code.
But when running, for example, the following lines the output is printed in the console, but not on the Shiny App.

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))
print(x)
```

[image]

How do I make this output appear on the Shiny app?

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

ui <- fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      tagList(wellPanel(uiOutput("plotorprint")))
        ),
    wellPanel(
        aceEditor("code", mode = "r", height = "100px", 
                  highlightActiveLine = FALSE, 
                  showLineNumbers = FALSE, 
                  minLines = 2,  
                  maxLines = 30, 
                  fontSize = 16, 
                  autoScrollEditorIntoView = TRUE,
                  placeholder = "CONSOLE"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ace_obj <- reactive({
    eval(parse(text=input$code))
  })

 
  output$printout <- renderPrint({
    ace_obj()
  })
  
  output$plotout <- renderPlot({        
    ace_obj()
  })
  
  output$plotorprint <- renderUI({
    if (is.data.frame(ace_obj)) { # Check if output of f(x) is data.frame
      verbatimTextOutput("printout") # If so, create a print
    } else {                      # If not,
      plotOutput("plotout") # create a plot
    }
  })
  
  
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm trying to display output in the white space above the console panel.

[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure whether shinyAce works with interactive plots in shiny

Answer (score -1):

You could use `req()` (require) to only evaluate `renderPrint` and `renderPlot` if your condition is met (you can add as many conditions as you like for both plot and print in require):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    tagList(wellPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("printout"),
      plotOutput("plotout")
    ))
  ),
  wellPanel(
    aceEditor("code", mode = "r", height = "100px", 
              highlightActiveLine = FALSE, 
              showLineNumbers = FALSE, 
              minLines = 2,  
              maxLines = 30, 
              fontSize = 16, 
              autoScrollEditorIntoView = TRUE,
              placeholder = "CONSOLE"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ace_obj <- reactive({
    eval(parse(text=input$code))
  })
  
  
  output$printout <- renderPrint({
    req(ace_obj(), is.data.frame(ace_obj()))
    ace_obj()
  })
  
  output$plotout <- renderPlot({        
    req(ace_obj())
    ace_obj()
  })
  
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler solution including `renderUI` is fixing the if-condition. `ace_obj` is a reactive object and is evaluated only with `ace_obj()`:

```r
output$plotorprint <- renderUI({
  if (is.data.frame(ace_obj())) { # Check if output of f(x) is data.frame
    verbatimTextOutput("printout") # If so, create a print
  } else {                      # If not,
    plotOutput("plotout") # create a plot
  }
})
```

Then evaluate in your interactive shiny console without `print()`:

```r
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))
x
```